# Automate vim execution on a file

Tags: vim, text-editing

I would like to be able to specify on bash command line set of keys that will vim execute on given file, just the same as I am doing it when manually editing, for instance, hypothetically:

```
vim myfile +'Gosome footer here<ESC>ggOsome header here<ESC>x'
```

I know that + executes Ex commands. Is there a way to do that? Using vim only of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, just add `normal` in front of the commands:

```
vim -c 'normal Gosome footer here' -c 'normal ggOsome header here' -c x myfile
```

The argument given to `-c` is evaluated in command-mode, so to execute normal commands you need to prepend `normal`.

Comment: Thanks m8. Thats very close to what I want. Can't I use hotkeys ? '10-commands-limit' seems pretty low

Comment: @majkinetor: hotkeys? If you're generating commands to run, you could write them to a file and then execute vim with `vim -c 'source cmdfile' myfile`. You may also want to look up `-s scriptin` and `-w scriptout` or `-W scriptout` in the man page, they make it easy to repeat macros across many files.